# How to change font family of this div which is present on different page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi can you please tell me how to change the font family of div .Actually i have one option to change font family in my application.After changing font family it should reflect on all application.But more important to one div (present different page )having some ID and  class.How to do that .

```
    $(document).on('change', '#select-choice-1', function() {


     var fontFamily = $(this).val() ; 
      var classesToChange = ".ui-body-c,.ui-btn-text,.ui-li-divider,.ui-header,.ui-li,.panel,.realtimeContend_h";
      $(classesToChange).css("font-family", fontFamily);


    });


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Font Family:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                            <option>Select Font family</option>
                           <option value="AntiquaAntiqua">AntiquaAntiqua</option>
                            <option value="Arial">Arial </option>
                           <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                             <option value="Corbel">Corbel</option>
                              <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

Div on other page

 <div id="realTimeContents" class="realtimeContend_h">

sdsdfjdsjfkldf;gkd;sklfdfgkldlfg;ld;'gl'dlfgsjkkjkldl;sdf;dfs;;dsfkksdll;;sdkshfhsdfjsieiryidsmfnksdjf
sdsdfjdsjfkldf;gkd;sklfdfgkldlfg;ld;'gl'dlfgsjkkjkldl;sdf;dfs;;dsfkksdll;;sdkshfhsdfjsieiryidsmfnksdjf
sdsdfjdsjfkldf;gkd;sklfdfgkldlfg;ld;'gl'dlfgsjkkjkldl;sdf;dfs;;dsfkksdll;;sdkshfhsdfjsieiryidsmfnksdjf
sdsdfjdsjfkldf;gkd;sklfdfgkldlfg;ld;'gl'dlfgsjkkjkldl;sdf;dfs;;dsfkksdll;;sdkshfhsdfjsieiryidsmfnksdjf
sdsdfjdsjfkldf;gkd;sklfdfgkldlfg;ld;'gl'dlfgsjkkjkldl;sdf;dfs;;dsfkksdll;;sdkshfhsdfjsieiryidsmfnksdjf
                            </div>  


$(document).on('change', '#select-choice-2', function() {
alert("dd")
    var style;
    var font = $(this).val();
    if ($('head').find('style.font').length === 0) {
        style = $('<style class="font">.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }</style>');
        $('head').append(style);
        $('body *').addClass('font');
    } else {
        $('body *').removeClass('font');
        $('style.font').empty();
        style = '.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }';
        $('style.font').append(style);
       }


});
```

Comment: using jQuery, you can only change what is available on current page. To make changes Application wide, I'd recommend using some server side logic to store font family and then Apply it either when page load (jQuery document ready function) or using CSS class that is applied on the server when generating HTML

Comment: But i am able to change font size like that of this div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global jquery object and store what user selected, then when the other page is loaded apply what user selected on the previous page example:
On the first page put this

```
$.selected = $("#select option:selected").val()
```

Now on the other page put this script inside the page div

```
<script>    
    $("#div").css('font-family',$.selected);
</scrpit>
```

That how I store and move infromation from one page to other, since everything is dynamic with jquery mobile, and I just query server for data, I use jquery global object and store info there.

Comment: can you please tell me how to search a text from page .With Next and previous button also?

Comment: yes but that is complicated, I have something like that in my app with next and previous, but I am not sure can I give you the code since its company's app

Comment: I will not share with others .If you can help me

Comment: can you give some demo on fiddle?

Comment: i will give you fiddle but I dont have time now, so later all post here

Comment: Ok Thanks.But truly speaking i need now ..!! i try a lot of things i also share with you but not working .I need to give build to tester ..:(

Answer (score 2):

This will not work like you expect. Javascript is client-based, which means that the changes you do is only reflected on what is happening on your screen right now.

If you want to have a site which remembers what font-family, settings, history etc your visitors have, you have to use a server-side language and program it.

This can easily be done with for example `PHP` by doing an ajax-call when you change font. In the script executed by the ajax-call you can set a cookie or session-value and then use this value to reflect the desired font-family each time you render a page by either outputting raw css or by adding/toggling classes.

Comment: May be you are right ..!! I don't have Much idea..so you are telling that server side change the fontfamily.? or If i need to change font family i need to put on same page ?

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem with this -- if I am understanding correctly -- is that you want to change the font application-wide. The problem is that the css will define what the font is across the the browser session. Just changing it in the document one time will not refresh it across the browser session, meaning when a user refreshes the page or clicks a link to go to another page, the original css will be used, not their change.

There are many ways you could do this:

1) cookies
2) session variables server side
3) queryline variables
4) plus any many others ...

Sample code of something that would work. I am using th carhart jquery cookie plug-in for simplicity's sake. (See that here https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
$(document).on('change', '#select-choice-2', function() {
alert("dd")
    var style;
    var font = $(this).val();
    if ($('head').find('style.font').length === 0) {
        style = $('<style class="font">.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }</style>');
        $('head').append(style);
        $('body *').addClass('font');


    } else {
        $('body *').removeClass('font');
        $('style.font').empty();
        style = '.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }';
        $('style.font').append(style);
       }

    //additional code
       $.cookie("font", font);
});

$(document).ready(function(){

if($.cookie("font"))
{
   var font = $.cookie("font");
   style = $('<style class="font">.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }</style>');
            $('head').append(style);
}

});
```

Not sure if that is exactly how you would want it to work, but something along that line. Basically, every time the DOM loads it needs to see if the font cookie is set. If so, then it sets the font stored in the cookie.

There are many other ways (and prob better ways) to do this, but this is just a simple example to get you started. Hope that helps.